# Laravel - how to access Cookie in controller

Tags: laravel, cookies

I'm new to working with cookies, and I'm having trouble understanding how to access Cookies in Laravel.

Context: I'm trying to build a shopping cart. User's order details are stored in SQL. If the user is a guest I use a cookie (session ID) to identify these SQL rows, if user is logged in I use their user ID. If the user starts out as a guest and then logs in, I'd like to change this identifier from being the cookie (session ID) to their user ID.

Problem: The 2nd line in the code below (which would achieve the above) never triggers. I can see that the SQL rows are being generated correctly and the cookie is being created, but the Cookie::get('id') just seems to return null. How can I get the Cookie value in that line?

If you need more details please let me know. Thanks a lot in advance!

Code (from add-to-cart controller)

```
 if (Auth::check()) {
 if (Orders::where(['status' => 'cart', 'cookie_id' => Cookie::get('id')])->exists()) {
 // Didn't include code here for simplicity. But code here never fires anyway
 }
 } else {
 if (Cookie::get('id') == null) {
 Cookie::queue('id', Session::getId(), 50000);
 $cookie_id = Session::getId();
 } else {
 $cookie_id = Cookie::get('id');
 Cookie::queue('id', Session::getId(), 50000);
 }
// There is then code to identify the SQL row using the Cookie (session) ID. User ID is just set to 1 by default, where that user is not a real user (was just my way to get around foreign key requirement)
Orders::create(['session_id' => $_POST['sessions_id'], 'cookie_id' => $cookie_id, 'qty' => $_POST['nr_students'], 'order_id' => $o_id, 'status' => 'cart', 'user_id' => 1]);
```

Comment: mention the laravel version please,also you might want to consider using  laravel session instead of creating a new cookie

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try on add-to-cart method a `Request` instance and get cookie value from that. Something like:

```
public function addToCart(Request $request)
{
   $myCookieValue = $request->cookie('cookie_name');
   ...
}
```